# Problem trying to scrape a JS web with requests-html (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I've passed the last week trying to scrape information from Epic Games Store webpage (https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/), I first tried using the Requests module, but I soon realized I needed a module which supports javascript webs.
And that's what I'm trying now, but there is a problem...
When I use "inspect element" on the page, everything's fine, but when I execute this:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get("https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/")
r.html.render()

print(r.html.html)
```

The result is an unreadable html file without most of the elements loaded.
Result: https://pastebin.com/zQ9m1gr2

You can test this, pick a game from the web and then ctrl + f It's name in the result file. You will realize there are no matches.
What can I do?

Thank you in advance! :)

**Edit:** It occurs exactly the same when I download the HTML from the browser manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the main page not containing the data you look for means that, store data is received after. So we can use `requests` to get the data by simulating what browser did.

If you look network tab in developer tools, you will see that when the page loads, it receives store data from `graphql` endpoint. That means if you simulate the request, you can get the store data:

```py
import requests

endpoint = "https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql"


# This query thing is what was sent to the server
# when loading the page, I couldn't figure out how
# to write it ourselves so I basically copy pasted
# the binary data in the payload.
query = b'{"query":"\\n            query storefrontDiscoverQuery(\\n              $locale:String,\\n              $country:String\u0021\\n            )  {\\n              Storefront {\\n                storefrontModules(locale: $locale) {\\n                  ... on StorefrontBreaker {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    titleGroup\\n                    description\\n                    backgroundColors\\n                    layout\\n                    link {\\n                      src\\n                      linkText\\n                    }\\n                    image {\\n                      src\\n                      alt\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontFreeGames {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontCardGroup {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                    }\\n                    offers {\\n                      namespace\\n                      id\\n                      offer {\\n                        \\n          title\\n          id\\n          namespace\\n          description\\n          keyImages {\\n            type\\n            url\\n          }\\n          seller {\\n              id\\n              name\\n          }\\n          urlSlug\\n          items {\\n            id\\n            namespace\\n          }\\n          customAttributes {\\n            key\\n            value\\n          }\\n          categories {\\n            path\\n          }\\n          price(country: $country) {\\n            totalPrice {\\n              discountPrice\\n              originalPrice\\n              voucherDiscount\\n              discount\\n              fmtPrice(locale: $locale) {\\n                originalPrice\\n                discountPrice\\n                intermediatePrice\\n              }\\n            }\\n            lineOffers {\\n              appliedRules {\\n                id\\n                endDate\\n              }\\n            }\\n          }\\n          linkedOfferId\\n          linkedOffer {\\n            effectiveDate\\n            customAttributes {\\n              key\\n              value\\n            }\\n          }\\n        \\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontFeaturedCarousel {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    slides {\\n                      title\\n                      eyebrow\\n                      description\\n                      backgroundColor\\n                      image {\\n                        src\\n                        alt\\n                      }\\n                      mobileImage {\\n                        src\\n                        alt\\n                      }\\n                      link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                  ... on StorefrontTiles {\\n                    type\\n                    title\\n                    tiles {\\n                      label\\n                      genre\\n                      link {\\n                        src\\n                        linkText\\n                      }\\n                    }\\n                  }\\n                }\\n              }\\n            }\\n            ","variables":{"locale":"en-US","country":"US"}}'

data = requests.post(endpoint, headers={"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                                       }, data=query)
print(data.json())
```

And it gives us [this data](https://pastebin.com/JfQZ8gn3). (Be careful, its pretty big.)

And also you can get per product information by using this:

```py
import requests, json

endpoint = "https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql"

query = {
    "query": "\n        query catalogQuery(\n            $productNamespace:String!,\n            $offerId:String!,\n            $locale:String,\n            $country:String!,\n            $lineOffers: [LineOfferReq]!) {\n                Catalog {\n                    catalogOffer(namespace: $productNamespace,\n                        id: $offerId,\n                        locale: $locale) {\n                            namespace\n                            effectiveDate\n                            id\n                            customAttributes {\n                                key\n                                value\n                            }\n                            items {\n                                id\n                                status\n                                customAttributes {\n                                    key\n                                    value\n                                }\n                            }\n                    }\n                }\n                PriceEngine {\n                    price(country: $country, lineOffers: $lineOffers) {\n                        totalPrice {\n                            discountPrice\n                            originalPrice\n                            voucherDiscount\n                            discount\n                            currencyCode\n                            currencyInfo {\n                                decimals\n                            }\n                            fmtPrice(locale: $locale) {\n                                originalPrice\n                                discountPrice\n                                intermediatePrice\n                            }\n                        }\n                        lineOffers {\n                            appliedRules {\n                                endDate\n                                discountSetting {\n                                    discountType\n                                }\n                            }\n                        }\n                    }\n                }\n            }\n        ",
    "variables": {
        "productNamespace": "cosmos",
        "offerId": "1c55202badfc4212b4f82553d5d22c3e", # This is found in the first request we made,
        "locale": "en-US",                             # data.Storefront.storefrontModules[1].offers[""0""].id to be more precise.
        "country": "US",
        "lineOffers": [{
            "offerId": "1c55202badfc4212b4f82553d5d22c3e", # The same id goes here too.
            "quantity": 1
        }],
        "calculateTax": False}
    }

data = requests.post(endpoint, headers={"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                                       }, data=json.dumps(query)) # We added json.dumps because it basically turns dictionary
                                                                  # into JSON string.
print(data.json())
```

That gives us:

```
{
  "data": {
    "Catalog": {
      "catalogOffer": {
        "namespace": "cosmos",
        "effectiveDate": "2019-07-12T00:00:00.000Z",
        "id": "1c55202badfc4212b4f82553d5d22c3e",
        "customAttributes": [
          {
            "key": "com.epicgames.app.blacklist",
            "value": "KR"
          },
          {
            "key": "isPrepurchase",
            "value": "true"
          },
          {
            "key": "availableDate",
            "value": "1573570800"
          },
          {
            "key": "developerName",
            "value": "Human Head Studios, Inc."
          }
        ],
        "items": [
          {
            "id": "70c30983cf0948e4bffc23505f232b11",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "customAttributes": [
              {
                "key": "SupportedPlatforms",
                "value": "Windows"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "974e25b4bce6425d9af79cd5ffd64152",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "customAttributes": [
              {
                "key": "SupportedPlatforms",
                "value": "Windows"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "159d92ebec254ecf8373709a99388a62",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "customAttributes": [
              {
                "key": "SupportedPlatforms",
                "value": "Windows"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "cc67628ab455419cb3d4ecc907febbb7",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "customAttributes": [
              {
                "key": "SupportedPlatforms",
                "value": "Windows"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "id": "2f742aa604a441d1a145f70411e9d8d2",
            "status": "ACTIVE",
            "customAttributes": [
              {
                "key": "SupportedPlatforms",
                "value": "Windows"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "PriceEngine": {
      "price": {
        "totalPrice": {
          "discountPrice": 2999,
          "originalPrice": 2999,
          "voucherDiscount": 0,
          "discount": 0,
          "currencyCode": "USD",
          "currencyInfo": {
            "decimals": 2
          },
          "fmtPrice": {
            "originalPrice": "$29.99",
            "discountPrice": "$29.99",
            "intermediatePrice": "$29.99"
          }
        },
        "lineOffers": [
          {
            "appliedRules": []
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cacheControl": {
      "version": 1,
      "hints": [
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items",
            0,
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items",
            1,
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items",
            2,
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items",
            3,
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "Catalog",
            "catalogOffer",
            "items",
            4,
            "customAttributes"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price",
            "totalPrice"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price",
            "totalPrice",
            "currencyInfo"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price",
            "totalPrice",
            "fmtPrice"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price",
            "lineOffers"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        },
        {
          "path": [
            "PriceEngine",
            "price",
            "lineOffers",
            0,
            "appliedRules"
          ],
          "maxAge": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently, you can get free-games-collection ids from [this url](https://www.epicgames.com/store/es-ES/api/content/collections/free-games-collection). Then you can query with this id to get the game list:

```py
import requests, json

endpoint = "https://graphql.epicgames.com/graphql"

gamesCollectionQuery = {
    "query":"\n            query catalogQuery($productNamespace:String!, $offerId:String!, $locale:String, $country:String!) {\n                Catalog {\n                    catalogOffer(namespace: $productNamespace, id: $offerId, locale: $locale) {\n                        title\n                        collectionOffers {\n                            \n          title\n          id\n          namespace\n          description\n          keyImages {\n            type\n            url\n          }\n          seller {\n              id\n              name\n          }\n          urlSlug\n          items {\n            id\n            namespace\n          }\n          customAttributes {\n            key\n            value\n          }\n          categories {\n            path\n          }\n          price(country: $country) {\n            totalPrice {\n              discountPrice\n              originalPrice\n              voucherDiscount\n              discount\n              fmtPrice(locale: $locale) {\n                originalPrice\n                discountPrice\n                intermediatePrice\n              }\n            }\n            lineOffers {\n              appliedRules {\n                id\n                endDate\n              }\n            }\n          }\n          linkedOfferId\n          linkedOffer {\n            effectiveDate\n            customAttributes {\n              key\n              value\n            }\n          }\n        \n                        }\n                        customAttributes {\n                            key\n                            value\n                        }\n                    }\n                }\n            }\n        ",
    "variables":{
        "productNamespace":"epic",
        "offerId":"7f22b3b15abc4821bba634340e2dd1ef",
        "locale":"es-ES",
        "country":"EN"
    }
}

data = requests.post(endpoint, headers={"Content-type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
                                       }, data=json.dumps(gamesCollectionQuery))

print(data.content)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, I would have never realized. Also, could you please help me one more time :s? What query I have to use If I want to get the price of (for example) this game: https://www.epicgames.com/store/en-US/product/rune-2/home ?

Comment: I updated the answer to suit your needs. You can pass the offer ids from last query we did.

Comment: And what about this page, I'm trying to get the games that appear here (It's the last one I promise) https://www.epicgames.com/store/es-ES/collection/free-games-collection ? I tried to do It by myself this time, but seems impossible without knowing JS, I'm sorry If I'm being annoying but this is the only impediment to start a small personal project, I'll understand If you don't want to waste your time with this ;) .

Comment: No problem :), I added to the answer. By the way in you should look at [this section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) if you will continue to use this platform.

Comment: Thank you again :D. Create new "posts" to make more questions instead what I've been doing, got It!

Comment: To answer your comment about free games, there is this URL: https://www.epicgames.com/store/backend/static/freeGamesPromotions