# Scrape Humble Bundle games using "Requests" module

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm actually trying get the information of the games contained in this webpage: `https://www.humblebundle.com/store/search?sort=discount&filter=onsale`

The first thing I tried was to replicate what one user did to help me on a similar problem days ago, doing a POST request to access directly where the data I need from the web comes from. [Here's the link of that question in case you still don't know what I'm trying to achieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59010090/problem-trying-to-scrap-a-js-web-with-requests-html-python-3-6).

To do that, I first executed this code to get the HTML file of the web without the elements loaded:

```
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.humblebundle.com/store/search?sort=discount&filter=onsale")

a = open("humble.txt", "w")
a.write(req.text)
a.close()
```

It returned me [this code](https://pastebin.com/LypA7PF3).

You can notice in the 1084 line a script called "storefront-constants-json-data", It called my attention because It was the unique that had some variables related to the page. Then I thought, "Hey, there must be more information about this script somewhere". The I clicked "Inspect element" on the web and went to the "Network" tab. I searched that script name in every JS file and found just one reference, [this one](https://humblebundle-a.akamaihd.net/static/hashed/64a1e024b3e129666572bfe2f5cd69a79dbfa1aa.js).

At this point I'm lost, In fact, I don't even know If I'm in the right way (because I don't know any JavaScript). Can someone show me the path to get those Humble Bundle games :s ?.

---

Pd: I wrote a similar question yesterday but It was very vague, so I decided to rewrite It giving all the information I have and explaining what I've tried.

Pd2: I'd prefer not to do It with Selenium or similar modules, they are too slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you see on the webpage is loaded through AJAX requests from different URL. If you open Network Inspector, you can see the URL of the requests - and the data are returned in Json format:

```
import requests

data = requests.get('https://www.humblebundle.com/store/api/search?sort=discount&filter=onsale&request=1').json()

from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

Prints:

```
{'num_pages': 245,
 'num_results': 4894,
 'page_index': 0,
 'request': 1,
 'results': [{'content_types': ['game'],
              'cta_badge': None,
              'current_price': [0.0, 'EUR'],
              'delivery_methods': ['download'],
              'empty_tpkds': {},
              'featured_image_recommendation': 'https://hb.imgix.net/2e18a2a9316c0136abf25670bf67ed389c855e4f.jpeg?auto=compress,format&fit=crop&h=154&w=270&s=64e2f8ad8654541c0620d8e018fa2025',
              'full_price': [0.01, 'EUR'],
              'human_name': 'Crying Suns Demo',
              'human_url': 'crying-suns-demo',
              'icon': 'https://hb.imgix.net/2e18a2a9316c0136abf25670bf67ed389c855e4f.jpeg?auto=format&fit=crop&h=64&w=103&s=dcf803da86b9bcf4cd2c0d038ddf16fb',
              'icon_dict': {'download': {'available': ['windows', 'mac'],
                                         'unavailable': ['linux']}},
              'large_capsule': 'https://hb.imgix.net/2e18a2a9316c0136abf25670bf67ed389c855e4f.jpeg?auto=compress,format&fit=crop&h=353&w=616&s=d50b680a5bfd2c6c6acdb4c745db8428',
              'machine_name': 'cryingsuns_demo_storefront',
              'non_rewards_charity_split': 0.0,
              'platforms': ['windows', 'mac'],
              'rating_for_current_region': 'pegi',
              'rewards_split': 0.1,
              'sale_end': 32503708740.0,
              'sale_type': 'normal',
              'standard_carousel_image': 'https://hb.imgix.net/2e18a2a9316c0136abf25670bf67ed389c855e4f.jpeg?auto=compress,format&fit=crop&h=206&w=360&s=015688fbe32c7e3e185bdcaddc72e02a',
              'type': 'product',
              'xray_traits_thumbnail': 'https://hb.imgix.net/2e18a2a9316c0136abf25670bf67ed389c855e4f.jpeg?auto=compress,format&fit=crop&h=84&w=135&s=eefaf495f9379b213672d82ddeae672a'},

...and so on.
```

---

The screenshot from network inspector:

[image]

Comment: I see, It was much more simple, good to know that before infinitely trying to do It with a post request, thank you very much!